# Drupal 6 Customize Search form with Taxonomy Drop down Box as a filter to narrow results. How to?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

How I can Include search block having Taxonomy Filter as drop down list box along with default text box. I tried Views exposed filter, but might be something I m doing wrong (as novice user ). I am having 3 vocabularies with their terms (hierarchical).So all 3 of these vocabulary and their terms should be in drop down list box. Could you please help me?

Comment: I think got answer using views and expose filters this could be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be possible via Views and exposed filters. More on this can be found at http://drupal.org/node/554656

Comment: Yep, it sounds like the Views module is what you need. Since you've answered your own question, you should mark it as "Accepted" so that others can benefit if they're looking for the same answer.